# search multiple field as regexp query in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, strapi

I am trying to search by different fields such as title and description. When i type keywords, elasticseach must found something if description or title includes that i typed keywords. This is my goal. How can i reach my goal?

You can see the sample code that i used for one field.

```
  query: {
          regexp: {
            title: `.*${q}.*`,
          },
        },
```

I also tried below one but it gave syntax error.

```
  query: {
          regexp: {
            title: `.*${q}.*`,
          },
          regexp: {
            description: `.*${q}.*`,
          },
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, you need to use a `bool` query.

```
GET /<you index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "title": ".*${q}.*"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "description": ".*${q}.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can find the documentation => [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)